# GAE - Python 3.7 - How to log?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, python-3.7

I have a google app engine project in python 3.7 in which I would like to write some logs.
I am used to program in app engine python 2.7 and I was using the simple code:

```
 logging.info('hi there!')
```

to write any log onto the google cloud log console.
That command above now doesn't work anymore and it says:

```
logging has no attribute 'info'
```

I searched and I found this possible new code

```
from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/l')
def hello():
    logging_client = logging.Client()
    log_name = LOG_NAME
    logger = logging_client.logger(LOG_NAME)
    text = 'Hello, world!'
    logger.log_text(text, severity='CRITICAL')
    return text
```

This code above doesn't give any error in the stack-driver report page BUT it displays nothing at all in the log page.

So how can I write a log for my app engine project in python3.7?

Comment: You are using the Standard Environment or the Flexible Environment?

Comment: Standard Environment @MilinduSanojKumarage

Comment: Are the logs missing just in local development or also when deployed on GAE?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know because my whole project can't work locally. So I can only say that nothing is displayed on GAE Log Console. @DanCornilescu

Answer (score 18):

The second generation standard environment (which includes python 3.7) is IMHO closer to the flexible environment than to the first generation standard environment (which includes python 2.7).

Many of the APIs which had customized versions for the 1st generation (maintained by the GAE team) were not (or at least not yet) ported in the 2nd generation if the respective functionality was more or less covered by alternate, more generic approaches, already in use in the flexible environment (most of them based on services developed and maintained by teams other than the GAE one).

You'll notice the similarity between many of the service sections in these 2 migration guides (which led me to the above summary conclusion):

- [Understanding differences between Python 2 and Python 3 on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences)
- [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating) (i.e 1st generation standard to flexible)

Logging is one of the services listed in both guides. The 1st generation used a customized version of the standard python `logging` library (that was before Stackdriver became a standalone service). For the 2nd generation logging was simply delegated to using the now generally available [Stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) service (which is what the snippet you shown comes from). From Logging (in the 1st guide):

> Request logs are no longer automatically correlated but will still
>   appear in Stackdriver Logging. Use the Stackdriver Logging client
>   libraries to implement your desired logging behavior.

The code snippet you show corresponds, indeed, to Stackdriver Logging. But you seem to be [Using the client library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) directly. I don't know if this is a problem (GAE is often a bit different), but maybe you could also try [using the standard Python logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) instead:

- [Connecting the library to Python logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#connecting_the_library_to_python_logging):

> To send all log entries to Stackdriver by attaching the Stackdriver
>   Logging handler to the Python root logger, use the `setup_logging`
>   helper method:
>
> ```
> # Imports the Google Cloud client library
> import google.cloud.logging
>
> # Instantiates a client
> client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
>
> # Connects the logger to the root logging handler; by default this captures
> # all logs at INFO level and higher
> client.setup_logging()
> ```

- [Using the Python root logger](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#using_the_python_root_logger):

> Once the handler is attached, any logs at, by default, INFO level or
>   higher which are emitted in your application will be sent to
>   Stackdriver Logging:
>
> ```
> # Imports Python standard library logging
> import logging
>
> # The data to log
> text = 'Hello, world!'
>
> # Emits the data using the standard logging module
> logging.warn(text)
> ```

There are some GAE-specific notes in there as well (but I'm not sure if they also cover the 2nd generation standard env):

> [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/) grants the [Logs Writer role](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) by default.
>
> The Stackdriver Logging library for Python can be used without needing
>   to explicitly provide credentials.
>
> Stackdriver Logging is automatically enabled for App Engine
>   applications. No additional setup is required.
>
> **Note**: Logs written to **stdout** and **stderr** are automatically sent to Stackdriver Logging for you, without needing to use
>   Stackdriver Logging library for Python.

Maybe worth noting that the [viewing the logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) would likely be different as well outside the 1st generation standard env (where app logs would be neatly correlated to the request logs).

And there's also the [Using Stackdriver Logging in App Engine apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging) guide. It doesn't specifically mention the 2nd generation standard env (so it might need an update) but has good hints for the flexible environment which *might* be useful. For example the [Linking app logs and requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#linking_app_logs_and_requests) section *might* be of interest if the missing request logs correlation has anything to do with it.

Comment: I works enough for me but to be precise this method writes 2 different logs: 1. 2018-10-31 11:49:56.330 CET
Hello, world! 2. 2018-10-31 11:49:56.330 CET
WARNING:root:Hello, world! AND no-one of them is recognized by the log console as a "normal" log, I mean, the square at the beginning of the line in the log console is gray and it doesn't display anyresponseSize nor latency here is an exemple: https://imgur.com/a/nOXtpGL

Comment: Try to skip the "connecting" step, it *might* eliminate one of the 2 messages (it may be already done for GAE). For the rest - I think it's related to that correlation. Not sure if the flex env recipe can actually be used. See also  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036936/4495081

Comment: Thanks, [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#connecting_the_library_to_python_logging) solved it for me. The only feature I am missing from python2 logging now is the fact that is that the request has no log level. In python2 it had levels based on what was being logged inside the request itself.

Comment: Has the issue of correlating logs ever been addressed? I have checked the docs and stackoverflow for the past hours, and the logs do not seem to be correlated or grouped under the request log

Answer (score 2):

Even though logging works differently in Python 2.7 and 3.7, the same method of logging provided in [Reading and Writing Application Logs in Python 2.7](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/#writing_application_logs) should work for Python 3.7 as well since logs written to stdout and stderr will still appear in the Stackdriver Logging.

```
Import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This is a debug message')

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.info('This is an info message')
logging.warning('This is a warning message')
logging.error('This is an error message')
logging.critical('This is a critical message')
#logging.warn is deprecated
logging.warn('This is a warning' message)

=======================================

Import logging

app.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
app.logger.error('This is an error message')
```

However, log entries are no longer automatically correlated with requests as in Python 2.7, which is why you see them in plain text. I have created a feature request to address this which you can follow [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/118770775).

Comment: No, your first suggestion doesn't work as I already said in my question and no, logging in python 3.7 doesn't work like in python 2.7 as said here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs
That being said your suggestion app.logger.error("hi!") worked BUT it resulted in a not good logged info in the log page it is only plain text like this: 2018-10-31 01:33:07.375 CET
ERROR:flask.app:This is an ERROR-level log message 
I need the log page to recognize the proprieties like this:
2018-10-31 01:33:01.237 CET
POST
405
337 B
2,6 s

Comment: It doesn't work. This is the code of the python 2.7 in GAE and doesn't work in python 3.7 in GAE. Try it yourself, please. As I already said app.logger.error() works but in a very bad way because it logs info using flask module but it isn't what I need. I need what you wrote in the first snippet but again, as you wrote it, it doesn't work, it says: logging module has no 'debug' attribute.

Comment: Yes, I tried it on my end, both work for Python 3.7. You need to add logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.info) but the error you are seeing “logging module has no ‘info' attribute” seems to be related to an issue finding the correct library. Please verify that there is not a file named “logging.py” in your directory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959188/absolute-import-failing-in-subpackage-that-shadows-a-stdlib-package-name